# Cannot redeclare user_data() error

Tags: php, mysql

i am creating a user accounts system for my website however when i use the  `include 'core/init.php';` function i get the error. This could be something really simple as I am a beginner and just learning.

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare user_data() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\PatchMyPC\core\functions\users.php:3) in C:\xampp\htdocs\PatchMyPC\core\functions\users.php on line 17
```

here is the code for my users.php & init.php files

init.php

```
<?php
session_start();
//error_reporting(0);

require 'database/connect.php';
require 'functions/users.php';
require 'functions/general.php';

if (logged_in() === true) {
    $session_user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $user_data = user_data($session_user_id, 'user_id', 'username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email');
    if (user_active($user_data['username']) === false) {
        session_destroy();
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    }
}

$errors = array();

?>
```

users.php

```
<?php

function user_data($user_id) {
$data = array();
$user_id = (int)$user_id;

$func_num_args = func_num_args();
$func_get_args = func_get_args();

if ($func_num_args > 1) {
    unset($func_get_args[0]);

    $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', $func_get_args) . '`';
    $data = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = $user_id"));
    return $data;
}
}

function logged_in() {
    return (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) ? true : false;
}

function user_exists($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    return (mysql_result($query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}

function user_active($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    return (mysql_result($query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `active` = 1"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}

function user_id_from_username($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'"), 0, 'user_id');
}

function login($username, $password) {
    $user_id = user_id_from_username($username);

    $username = sanitize($username);
    $password = md5($password);

    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'"), 0) ==1) ? $user_id : false;
}
?>
```

Comment: Sounds like you are either declaring the same function twice or including the same file twice. use `require_once()` instead of `require()`.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you require users.php twice.

use:

```
require_once('users.php');
```

in all your files to overcome this problem.